# iOS and android mobile app deep linking

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking

I'm trying to find a solution to create deep links to content within my app. In this scenario an iOS or android user of my app can tap an icon within the app which will generate the custom URl to that specific app page which the user can then share this link in an email. When this link opened by another user who has my app installed , that specific app page will open for that user . I'm not sure if it's possible to execute this for multiple app pages across platforms. I will appreciate any suggestions for this interesting and very useful feature . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [this is possible](https://blog.branch.io/mobile-deep-linking-101).

On Android, you will want to investigate [URI schemes](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes), [App Links](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links), and [Chrome Intents](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-on-android-chrome-intents).

On iOS, look at [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9). URI schemes are not really a good option on iOS anymore, but you may still want to implement them since Universal Links don't work everywhere yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, I will study the resources you sent in detail . I'm also going through these resources http://fokkezb.nl/2013/08/26/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-1/ .  This might be complex to execute but if I succeed it will be very handy for my users to share specific app pages to other users via these links !